# SVN, Restore previous state

Tags: svn

Help me to solve following problem with SVN.

I have 2 branches. First branch was under active development so it have some uncommitted changes. But in second (production) branch  I found a bug so I want to quickly fix it. So I switched from first branch (with uncommitted state) to second branch (where I want quickly fix a bug). And now first branch was merged to second (with many conflicts etc..)! I really don't know how to solve this problem. At minimum I want to revert all changes (not svn `revert` command, I mean to restore previous state, before swtiching from one branch to another)

i.e. I need to rollback last `switch` command

Comment: One of the advantages of subversion is that you can have the same project checked out in multiple working copies. Next time do that instead.

Comment: @BenVoigt ok, thanks. In fact I already decide to follow way like suggested you. But first I need to return to previous state.

Comment: unless you are working with an IDE that istself holds a local history from witch you can restore your conflicted files one by one, I am afrad you'll have to resolve the conflicts in each file manually. SVN generates conflict becaus it doesn't know how to handle the changes between the two versions, so it wants a human to look at them. To fix the bug in production, you should checkout a separate working copy for that branch and fix it there.

Comment: there is no way to revert it automatically via a subversion command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no better way than using your brain : your local copy is now messed up and you can't revert your action, there is no way to do it.

With some luck, your ide has an internal backup (thinkihng eclipse e.g.) and you can revert to a previous version of the file and salvage some of your work.

Rule of thumb for the future :

- never switch with local changes unless you know what you're doing
- keep different workspaces for different kind of works (I usually have a "fix" workspace and a few "dev" workspace)
- if you're using externals, than the evil can be even worse :-)